# go pprof heap profile vs top mem_usage

Tags: go, memory-profiling, pprof, heap-profiling

I am running go application and use pprof to get heap profile of it as below:

```
curl -s http://localhost:<port>/debug/pprof/heap > heap_profile.out
go tool pprof heap_profile.out
```

As a result, I get this: `Showing nodes accounting for 507.98MB, 99.41% of 510.98MB total`. But I don't know where does it get this 507.98MB in first place. When I check current memory usage using `top`, it shows that my application is using only 200MB memory (RES value in `top` command's result). Can somebody explain what is the difference between total in_use memory shown by heap profile and mem_usage given by `top` ?

Comment: What OS are you on? I'm not familiar with a `top` metric of `mem_usage` - typically you get separate metrics for virtual, shared, and resident memory, labelled `virt`, `shr`, and `res`, respectively.

Comment: @Adrian it is LinuxOS and I am referring to RES value.

Comment: `pprof` is a profiler, it tells you about heap allocations over time. Most of that will have been garbage collected, not actively in use, and therefor not reflected in a point-in-time snapshot of memory usage like that found in top.

Comment: I set env variable `GOGC=off` and restarted app and took heap profile. But there is still a difference and it is almost same.

Comment: I think this answers your question, it's in go [faq](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_does_my_Go_process_use_so_much_virtual_memory)

Comment: @nilsocket question is about resident memory, not virtual memory. Also it's about heap profiler showing *more* memory used than shown in top, not less.